# If statement returns only the result from the "else" statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am trying to make a script that compares the user input with another string. The problem is with my if statement. I don't get errors but it always returns the result that is in the "else" statement. Here is the code:

```
String [] lessons_titles = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90"};

final TextView dan_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DanText);
final int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
final String title = lessons_titles[position];

check_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String textField = check_text.getText().toString();
            if (textField == title){
                dan_view.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
                dan_view.setTextColor(Color.RED);                   
            }                           
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `equals()` method instead of `==` operator when you compare `String`. In case of `String`, two string will be equal if their reference are same and to find out that both of them referencing to the same point, you have to use `equals()` method. `==` operator can only compare primitive type value but instance of `String` is object.

So, your condition should be as follows...

```
if (textField.equals(title)){
    dan_view.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    dan_view.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` is for testing whether two strings are the same object; - reference equality.

You want to check the value so should use `.equals()`

Take a look at:

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
if (textField == title){ //<--
```

textField is a string, you need to check string equality using `.equals()`, e.g.

```
if (textField.equals(title)){ //<--
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 if (textField.compareTo(title) == 0)
 {
   dan_view.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
  else {
      dan_view.setTextColor(Color.RED);                   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"textField == title" Using == will check that they are the exact same, not just value wise but also stored in the same memory location.

Instead try using 
if (textField.equals(title)){

A good example is shown here http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/